# Help fix texture distortion in texture paint

Tags: texturing, uv, image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I modeled a low poly futuristic tank. I want to texture it using pixel art.
After creating the first UV of the side of the tank using ortho right view and project from view, I created a few lines in the UV editor but noticed a distortion.

I made a cross to show the distortion. On the left window is the edit view with all the faces selected. Note that the top line is not straight as it goes downwards to the right. On the right window is the UV/Image editor where in paint mode I painted a cross along 3 triangles. As you can see, in the middle triangle the cross is distorted.

[image: distortion]

Can anyone help me fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's another cross showing that the error is in that triangle.
I'd like to add that I can't paint in the 3d view, if I press the left mouse button and drag it, trying to draw a line, it doesn't do that and draws a single pixel, then nothing then another pixel far away. Sorry, that's the best I can describe it. So I paint in the UV/Image Editor.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried what happens when you paint your cross or anything else in the 3d view using Texture Paint mode? Also if you are using Project from View, can you check in the F6 panel in 3d view if the Orthographic is checked and Scale to Bounds?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! I added another screenshot to better show the issue. I tried pressing F6 in the 3d view but nothing happens besides a small text saying "texture paint toggle"

Comment: Sorry I have been offline for awhile- in a separate file, can you reproduce the error on a new plane that you subdivide with the knife tool to look like the same geo here? I am wondering if there is a problem with applying scale here.